# Has anyone ever used jwplayer to play multiple flv files consecutively? using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, flash, video-streaming, jwplayer

Has anyone ever used jwplayer to play multiple flv files consecutively?
Just to further clarify, what I'm wanting to know is when jwplayer has completed playing a video so I can begin it playing the next.

So far I can play a single movie but I can't play one after the other

code so far:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Public Class Form1
    Friend WithEvents AxShockwaveFlash1 As New AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash
    Dim PlayingFlash As Boolean = False
    Dim PlaylistHidden As Boolean = False
    Dim SettingUseJwPlayer3_16 As Boolean = True
    Sub OpenFLV(ByVal strFile As String, ByVal AxShockWaveFlash As AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash)
        Dim strPath As String
        Dim PlayerPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\player.swf"
        If File.Exists(PlayerPath) Then File.Delete(PlayerPath)
        File.WriteAllBytes(PlayerPath, My.Resources.player)
        strPath = "file:///" & PlayerPath & "?file="
        strPath = strPath & strFile
        strPath = Replace(strPath, "\", "/")
        With AxShockWaveFlash
            .Stop()
            .Visible = True
            .Menu = False
            .FlashVars = "&showstop=true&showdownload=false&height=" & AxShockWaveFlash.Height.ToString & "&width=" & AxShockWaveFlash.Width.ToString & "&showplay=true&autoscroll=false&autostart=true&overstretch=true&showicons=1&searchbar=false&controlbar=0"
            .LoadMovie(0, strPath)
            .Play()
        End With
        PlayingFlash = True
    End Sub
    Sub PlayJwPlayer3_16(ByVal Vid As String)
        If Not AxShockwaveFlash1.IsDisposed Then AxShockwaveFlash1.Dispose()
        AxShockwaveFlash1 = New AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash
        AxShockwaveFlash1.BeginInit()
        AxShockwaveFlash1.Name = "AxShockwaveFlash1"
        AxShockwaveFlash1.EndInit()
        Me.Controls.Add(AxShockwaveFlash1)
        AxShockwaveFlash1.Visible = True
        AxShockwaveFlash1.Location = Panel1.Location
        AxShockwaveFlash1.BringToFront()
        PlayingFlash = True
        Panel1.Visible = False
        OpenFLV(Vid, AxShockwaveFlash1)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Play_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Play.Click
        PlayJwPlayer3_16("https://dp-geography.wikispaces.com/file/view/World+Cup+in+South+Africa+-+%28IB+Geography+Study+Sports%2C+Leisure+%26amp%3B+Tourism+%29.flv")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why not use a playlist? What version of the JW Player are you using here? If you are using V5 or V6 you can use a playlist and just have one item repeat after another.

Comment: v3.16 how do I use a playlist with vb.net? If you could tell me that would be awesome. My code so far is above :-)

Right now the problem for me is I can't detect when one item is complete so as to start playback of the next

Comment: 3.16 is quite old. I had to go to archive.org ;)

http://web.archive.org/web/20080105051613/http://www.jeroenwijering.com/?item=Supported_Flashvars

autostart (true,false): Set this to true in the player to automatically start playing when the page loads, or set this to false with the rotator to prevent the automatic rotation.

repeat (true,false,list): Set this to true to automatically repeat playback of the file or playlist. Set this to list to playback all items in a playlist once.

Playlists - http://web.archive.org/web/20080106114940/http://www.jeroenwijering.com/?item=Supported_Playlists

Comment: Although your help is very good. Could you please help me with the coding? That's kinda why I asked for help in the first place

Comment: I am going to leave it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this for a repeating playlist.

Instead of:

```
PlayJwPlayer3_16("https://dp-geography.wikispaces.com/file/view/World+Cup+in+South+Africa+-+%28IB+Geography+Study+Sports%2C+Leisure+%26amp%3B+Tourism+%29.flv")
```

Use something like:

```
PlayJwPlayer3_16("https://dp-geography.wikispaces.com/file/playlist.xml")
```

Also for this part:

```
FlashVars = "&showstop=true&showdownload=false&height=" & AxShockWaveFlash.Height.ToString & "&width=" & AxShockWaveFlash.Width.ToString & "&showplay=true&autoscroll=false&autostart=true&overstretch=true&showicons=1&searchbar=false&controlbar=0"
```

Would look like:

```
&showstop=true&showdownload=false&height=" & AxShockWaveFlash.Height.ToString & "&width=" & AxShockWaveFlash.Width.ToString & "&showplay=true&autoscroll=false&autostart=true&overstretch=true&showicons=1&searchbar=false&controlbar=0&repeat=list"
```

Here is what a sample playlist would look like:

```
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
    <title>Example XSPF playlist for the JW Player</title>
    <info>http://www.longtailvideo.com</info>
    <tracklist>

        <track>
            <title>Big Buck Bunny - FLV Video</title>
            <creator>the Peach Open Movie Project</creator>
            <info>http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/</info>
            <annotation>Big Buck Bunny is a short animated film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation. Like the foundation's previous film Elephants Dream, the film is made using free and open source software.</annotation>
            <location>http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.flv</location>
        </track>

        <track>
            <title>Big Buck Bunny - MP3 Audio with thumb</title>
            <creator>the Peach Open Movie Project</creator>
            <info>http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/</info>
            <annotation>Big Buck Bunny is a short animated film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation. Like the foundation's previous film Elephants Dream, the film is made using free and open source software.</annotation>
            <location>http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp3</location>
            <image>http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.jpg</image>
        </track>

        <track>
            <title>Big Buck Bunny - PNG Image with start</title>
            <creator>the Peach Open Movie Project</creator>
            <info>http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/</info>
            <annotation>Big Buck Bunny is a short animated film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation. Like the foundation's previous film Elephants Dream, the film is made using free and open source software.</annotation>
            <location>http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.png</location>
            <meta rel="duration">20</meta>
            <meta rel="start">10</meta>
        </track>

        <track>
            <title>Big Buck Bunny - PNG Image with start</title>
            <creator>the Peach Open Movie Project</creator>
            <info>http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/</info>
            <annotation>Big Buck Bunny is a short animated film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation. Like the foundation's previous film Elephants Dream, the film is made using free and open source software.</annotation>
            <location>http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.png</location>
            <meta rel="duration">20</meta>
            <meta rel="start">10</meta>
        </track>
    </tracklist>
</playlist>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Replied above, wouldn't fit in comments

Comment: basically rather than allowing more than one clip to be played consecutively, when i tried what you suggested nothing played. Here is a link to my project files: http://sdrv.ms/VDXZDL

Comment: Hm, I took a look at the files. However, I don't have Visual Studio. I know embedding the player inside of a webpage will work (as that is the intended use case of the player itself), but I haven't used VS before, though.

Comment: It's so annoying :-) Feel like I'm so close

Comment: Just did a little research think the reason the playlist wouldn't work was because I'm using v3.16. Playlist support only came in with v5

Comment: What I've found is, I can't use the latest or even a newer version of jwplayer without a newer version of "AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll" which enables flash to be used in VB.Net (which has not been produced). Can you think of another way of playing multiple flvs consecutively?

Comment: We did support playlists all the way back to 3.16 though. JW4 and JW5 should both work. You can try with all of our old tagged versions here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/

I have not used VB.Net though, so that is where my expertise runs out, I'm afraid.